# CSS: align text at bottom; YouTube video breaking border in Chrome

Tags: css

The title needs to be at bottom of the text, and just above the video.  The border for the wrapper is breaking near the bottom left corner (because of the YouTube video) when viewed in Chrome.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body{font:15px arial,sans-serif;}

    img{border-style: none;}    

    a:link  {color:#0000FF;}       /*  unvisited  link  */
    a:visited  {color:#0000FF;}    /*  visited  link  */
    a:hover  {color:#0000FF;}      /*  mouse  over  link  */ 
    a:active  {color:#0000FF;}     /*  selected  link  */ 

    #title{
        font-size:130%;
        vertical-align:bottom; /*What am I doing wrong here? */
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    #arrows{
        float:left;
        margin-top:25px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    #list{
        float:right;
        margin-right:60px;
    }
    #wrapper{
        width:300px;
        border:  10px  solid  orange; /*Why is the YouTube video breaking this when viewed in Chrome? */
    }
    #video{
        margin:20px;
    }
</style>

</head>


<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="arrows">
            <br />
            <a href="javascript:down()"><img src='img/up.png'></a><br />
            <a href="javascript:up()">  <img src='img/down.png'></a>
        </div>
        <div id="list">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='...' id='0' >zero</a></li>
                <li><a href='...' id='1' >one</a></li>
                <li><a href='...' id='2' >two</a></li>
                <li><a href='...' id='3' >three</a></li>
                <li><a href='...' id='4' >four</li>
                <li><a href='...' id='5' >five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='title'>Beginner Tutorial 1</div>

        <div id='video'><embed style="width:260px; height:176px;" id="VideoPlayback" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docId=4204540069740232845&hl=en" flashvars=""> </embed></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move

```
<div id='title'>Beginner Tutorial 1</div>
```

below the

```
<div id='video'><embed style="width:260px; height:176px;" id="VideoPlayback" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docId=4204540069740232845&hl=en" flashvars=""> </embed></div>
```

but before the last

```
</div>
```

This happened because your other elements are floated and, therefore, are outside the flow of the document.

EDIT: I don't see the border issue in Chrome, BTW.

EDIT #2: To place the `div id-title` above the video, add the following line above the title:

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

Comment: Floated elements aren't really removed from the flow -- that's absolutely positioned elements -- but their parents do not automatically expand height to contain their height unless the parent is also floated, or contains a clearing element after the float.. They still do have layout impact on adjacent elements, whether they're floated or not. But your answer will still be helpful.

Comment: John, vertical-align: bottom doesn't mean what you're taking it to mean (though most of us wish it did). Vertical-align is about where inline elements will sit with regard to other inline elements on the same line. http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/ has a decent illustrated example.

Comment: Jason, thanks for your help.  I apologize because I realize I mis-spoke: the title needs to be below the text,,, but above the video. (I just edited the question)

Comment: No problem.  You just need to add this above the title: 

`<br style="clear:both;" />`

 but after the list.  I've changed the answer above.